# Get the different name of column between 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server database, I have the same table name in different schemas. For instance `schema1.card` (table 1) and `schema2.card` (table 2).

There are around 40 tables in my database. I just want to compare both tables and want to know which are the **different column names** between those 2 tables.

I have attached a screenshot of the tables. I want to find out all columns which are not in table 2 but exist in table 1 and vice versa.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Information_schema or sys.columns

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'card' and table_schema = 'schema1'
except
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'card' and table_schema = 'schema2'
```

--With full join

```
select * from information_schema.columns t1
full join information_schema.columns t2 
on t1.table_catalog=t2.table_catalog
and t1.column_name = t2.column_name
where
t1.table_name = 'card' and t2.table_name = 'card'
and t1.table_schema = 'schema1' and t2.table_schema = 'schema2'
and (t1.column_name is null or t2.column_name is null)
```

Comment: Hi @kannan-kandasamy,I would like to know about the column names which are not exist in schema 2 and vice versa .While your query gives the detail of all the column in schema1.

Comment: you can use vice versa of the query... If you want both to be in same query then use full outer join

Answer (score 0):

```
select Column_Name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'sysjobs' and table_schema = 'YourSchema1'
except
select Column_Name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'sysjobservers' and table_schema = 'YourSchema2'
```

Also, what you can do it is create a variable and loop through all schemas and put the difference in a temporary table. This way you do not have to do one by one and you can automate it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add one column in my second schema and wrote following query adn I got the output what I want.

```
    select * from information_schema.columns t1 where t1.table_name = 'card' and   t1.table_schema = 'Custom' and 
t1.column_name not in(select t2.column_name from information_schema.columns t2 where  t2.table_name = 'card' and   t2.table_schema = 'boston' )
```